# sampling method in moderation analysis

Tags: sampling

correct me if I'm wrong, I've read that my sample should be normally distributed if I'm going to use moderation analysis. But if in case I'll be using purposive sampling (I'm following certain criteria / conditions )what can I do as a solution in the problem of normal distribution? my last question will be, is moderating variables needed to be tested with normal distribution aside from Independent variable? Thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample does not need to be normally distributed to use moderation analysis. Where did you read this? You may be be thinking of the residuals from the model.

Purposive sampling has not much to do with the distribution of the data; it will affect estimation of parameters.

Neither the moderating nor the independent variable has to be normally distributed. Indeed, they could be dichotomous or categorical.